# What is the difference between the release and integration versions?

Tags: windowbuilder

I just grabbed the JDK & eclipse classic and I am trying to figure out which one to use for installation. What is the differences between the release and integration versions provided by eclipse.org: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Answer (score 2):

Well, I dunno for sure. But i've checked the hash(md5/sha1) of both for zipped one. And the hash is exactly the same. For example, 3.8 :

http://eclipse.org/downloads/sums.php?file=/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201302221200/WB_v1.5.2_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.8.zip.MD5&type=md5

http://eclipse.org/downloads/sums.php?file=/windowbuilder/WB/integration/WB_v1.5.2_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.8.zip.MD5&type=md5

Theoritically, it should be the same file. But, i dunno for sure though...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, there should be a reason why they put two links. The reason provided by @Aram is reasonable

Answer (score 2):

I think the files are the same, but URLs are different. If you use the Release version, you will always have the URL of that particular version in Eclipse URL list, while the Integration version will provide a single URL for all future versions for that particular Eclipse version (say 4.4)

Answer (score 1):

I have found only that the "Integration Version" is longer(39891450 bytes) than the "Release Version"(39759975 bytes).

The name for each .jar file in the "Integration Version" contains substring "20141006" (for example: org.eclipse.wb.swing.FormLayout_1.7.0.r44x201410061440.jar)

The name of each .jar file in the "Release Version"     contains substring "20140502" (for example: org.eclipse.wb.swing.FormLayout_1.7.0.r44x201405021531.jar)

Links:

Integration Version:
http://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/windowbuilder/WB/integration/WB_v1.7.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse4.4.zip

Release Version:
http://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201406251200/WB_v1.7.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse4.4.zip

So, it seems the "Integration Version" is newer version.